# DataConnectionDialog with active diretory as authentication type

Tags: .net, sql-server, c#-4.0, active-directory

Is it possible to use DataConnectionDialog**  using Active Directory (an external one) as authentication type? I can only see two methods of authentication (Sql Server and windows authentication)

If it is not possible with DataConnectionDialog, is there another way to achive it?

**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.data.dataconnectiondialog?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Answer (score 0):

I just realized it is possible to set up authentication method via advanced settings.

[image]

[image]